# Xamarin Studio Error MSB4018: The "ConvertResourcesCases" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform, xamarin-studio

I am getting the following error while trying to build my solution. I am trying to update an existing project that I haven't touched for a few months. Its location in my PC has not changed.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error MSB4018: The "ConvertResourcesCases" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'obj\Debug\res\anim\slide_out_left.xml'.
File name: 'obj\Debug\res\anim\slide_out_left.xml'
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)
at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.CopyIfChanged(String source, String destination)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ConvertResourcesCases.FixupResources(ITaskItem item, Dictionary2 acwMap)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ConvertResourcesCases.FixupResources(Dictionary2 acwMap)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ConvertResourcesCases.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext() (MSB4018) (TekaTekiMalaysia.Droid)
```

I've read from the other thread that I've to 'Unblock' the file via File Explorer but such option is not available for me under properties.

I've also tried moving the solution to a different folder up the folder tree.

I've also tried changing the folder properties by giving it `Full Control` permission.

I am using Xamarin Studio to build the project. Any ideas what is causing the issue?

Comment: Are you able to open `obj\Debug\res\anim\slide_out_left.xml` outside of Xamarin Studio?

Comment: `slide_out_left.xml` is missing from the `obj\Debug\res\anim\`   but I can open it from its original location which is `Resources\anim` without problem. Each time I rebuild the solution, a different file is reported not found and the build failed.

Comment: What version of Xamarin Studio are you using? Also what happens if you delete the `obj\Debug` folder?

Comment: I am using version 5.10.1 (build 6). If I delete `obj\Debug` it will be recreated again on the next build action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I finally figured it out. For the benefit of those encountering the same problem here's how I fix it. It's caused by any non English character in the root solution folder.

For example my original solution location is

```
D:\Users\OneDrive\Dev\Xamarin\TekaTeki3\TekaTeki3\
```

I created a new folder and rename the folder from `TekaTeki3` to `TekaTekiTiga`. Now it compiles properly!

```
D:\Users\OneDrive\Dev\Xamarin\TekaTekiTiga\TekaTeki3\
```

Answer (score 2):

Deleting bin and debug folder/Changing the solution directory name nothing worked, I solved it by moving the solution from "C:\Users\Dell PC\Desktop\studies\SampleProjects\Xamarin\XamarinFCM" to "C:\XamarinSamples\XamarinFCM"

What I feel is xamarin solution expect a shorter directory path. not sure why Microsoft leave this kind of bug.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by cleaning my solution, deleting the obj and bin directories in my **.Droid** project and rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine there's a bug but here's a workaround:

The error is telling us it can't find a directory.

Create the directories manually, then rebuild. 
There will be 3 new missing directory complaints - just manually create those directories as well.

Rebuild-All should work now.

Comment: The directories are not missing they are already there. Nonetheless, I tried recreating them and copy the content from the original one and delete the original. But the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

For me this Solution works, I have only shorten the Path of solution like,

previously it was

> D:\Projects\Xamarin_Projects\Git_Test\WCP_Solution

I shifted my project location to shorter path like

> D:\Projects\WCP_Solution

because there is character limit Android solution

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem. The fix was add "READ & WRITE" on root folder and **rebuild **the project.

Comment: Does not work. Removing bin and obj folder can fix, but I don't think it is an acceptable solution because this issue happens so many times every day, I cannot remove them every time I build.